# How to Use Flutter AlertDialog in Catch Block ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, try-catch

I'm trying to check if the user logged in or the email-password data is wrong. Here is my code.

```
onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email: email!, password: password!);
                        if (user != null) {
                          var customerInfo = CustomerInfo(email: email);
                          await customerInfo.getCustomerData();
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => CustomerScreen(
                                      customerInfo: customerInfo)));
                        }
                      } catch (e) {
                        AlertDialog(
                          title: Text("Warning!"),
                          content: Text("Email or Password is wrong!"),
                          actions: [
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text("Yes"),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }
                    },
```

However,when I write wrong email and password nothing happends. How can I use alertdialog in my catch block?

Comment: Try to show AlertDialog in else part of the if(user !=null) {} else{ your AlertDialog}

Comment: @TusharPatel I tried that too. Nothing happens

Comment: then print the user value, and accordingly perform action.

Comment: @TusharPatel I did not understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your AlertDialog Widget with showDialog methond and put your dialog in else block too.

```
   onPressed: () async {
      try {
        final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email!, password: password!);
        if (user != null) {
           var customerInfo = CustomerInfo(email: email);
           await customerInfo.getCustomerData();
           Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => CustomerScreen(customerInfo: customerInfo)),
              );
         } else {
            await showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                     title: Text("Warning!"),
                     content: Text("Email or Password is wrong!"),
                     actions: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                           onPressed: () {},
                           child: Text("OK"),
                        ),
                     ],
                  );
               },
            );
          }
       } catch (e) {
           await showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                     title: Text("Warning!"),
                     content: Text("Email or Password is wrong!"),
                     actions: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                           onPressed: () {},
                           child: Text("OK"),
                        ),
                     ],
                  );
               },
           );                 
       }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose you AlertDialog with showDialog and instead alertbox  in catch block use if(user !=null) {} else{ your AlertDialog}

```
await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Warning!"),
             content: Text("Email or Password is wrong!"),
              actions: [
               ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("OK"),
                ),
              ],
            );
             },
         );
```

Comment: Still no luck. I can not see anything.

Comment: can you try printout what is returning in `user`@sonelektrikci

Comment: When I click the login button with wrong user credentials, even my print function does not work. Awkward.

Comment: try like this print(" print data $user");@sonelektrikci

Comment: I tried this in else statement. However it does not work. Else statement does not work somehow.

Comment: have you tried to print catch block@sonelektrikci

Comment: I cant cuz I implemented the user in if statement.

Comment: without anything we can't help you man,there is nothing shows in result.it kind of hard to tell@sonelektrikci

Comment: If statement code working. When  I give valid information, I can push the other page. However, else statement does not work. I dont know why. It does not even print the print(user).

Comment: Ok then print the user in try block, right after when you fetch the user, check the value of user first then update the question what is the value of user.